# Filtering objects array with an inside array with another array

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's use the following code example to elaborate on my question:

```
struct exampleObj {
    var str: String?
    var arr: [String]?
}

let filterArray = ["something1", "ins1", "something2"]

let obj1 = exampleObj(str: "obj1", arr: ["ins2", "ins3"])
let obj2 = exampleObj(str: "obj2", arr: ["ins1", "ins2"])
let obj3 = exampleObj(str: "obj3", arr: ["ins1", "ins4"])
let obj4 = exampleObj(str: "obj4", arr: ["ins3", "ins4"])

var arrayObj = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]

let result = arrayObj.filter { filterArray.contains($0.arr...)} //??? I get lost here, dunno if right approach.
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter `arrayObj` by using another array `filterArray`, resulting on a `result` with only objects of type `exampleObj` containing `ins1`.

I hope I was clear. Any doubt about the question, I'm here.

Comment: Whats the purpose of declaring your properties optional if they will never be nil? `struct ExampleObj {
    let str: String
    let arr: [String]
}` btw it is Swift naming convention to name your structures starting with an UppercaseLetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find matches where there is an intersection between values of the two arrays. This is more easily done with sets. You also need to deal with `arr` being optional.

```
let result = arrayObj.filter { !Set(filterArray).intersection($0.arr ?? []).isEmpty }
```

This would be more efficient if you declare `filterArray` as a `Set` to begin with.

```
let filterSet: Set = ["something1", "ins1", "something2"]

let obj1 = exampleObj(str: "obj1", arr: ["ins2", "ins3"])
let obj2 = exampleObj(str: "obj2", arr: ["ins1", "ins2"])
let obj3 = exampleObj(str: "obj3", arr: ["ins1", "ins4"])
let obj4 = exampleObj(str: "obj4", arr: ["ins3", "ins4"])

var arrayObj = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]

let result = arrayObj.filter { !filterSet.intersection($0.arr ?? []).isEmpty }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```swift
let result = arrayObj.filter { obj in
    filterArray.contains { filter in
        obj.arr?.contains(filter) ?? false
    }
}
```

or using `Set`:

```swift
let result = arrayObj.filter { !Set(filterArray).isDisjoint(with: $0.arr ?? []) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do by finding `non-empty` `intersection` between `filterArray` and `exampleObj's arr`, i.e.

```
let filterSet = Set(filterArray)
let result = arrayObj.filter { (exampleObj) -> Bool in
    if let arr = exampleObj.arr {
        return !filterSet.intersection(arr).isEmpty
    }
    return false
}
```

**Output:** `result` contains `obj1` and `obj2`.